# Let $I⊂\mathbb R$ be an interval and suppose $f:I→\mathbb R$ is differentiable and $f':I→\mathbb R$ is bounded. Show $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$ be metric spaces. For $L>0$, a function $f : X → Y$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous if$$d_Y(f(x), f(x')) ≤ Ld_X(x,x').\quad\forall x, x'\in X$$We say $f:X→Y$ is Lipschitz continuous if $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous for some $L>0$.

(a) Show that if $f : X →Y$ is Lipschitz continuous, then $f$ is continuous.

(b) Let $I ⊂ \mathbb R$ be an interval and suppose $f : I → \mathbb R$ is differentiable and $f': I → \mathbb R$ is bounded. Show $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

*For part a, is showing $f$ is uniformly continuous okay? or I can only show it is continuous?

*For part b, I do not know how to do this at all.

Comment: This is just an immediate consequence of the mean value theorem. Showing uniform continuity is fine, since uniform continuity is stronger than continuity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniformly continuous functions are continuous

For b) use Mean Value Theorem: $|f(x)-f(y)| =|x-y| |f'(\xi)|$ for some $\xi$ which gives $|f(x)-f(y)|  \leq L|x-y|$ where $L$ is an upper bound for $|f'|$ .